# Does View class in MVC framework not have attributes/operations?

Tags: uml

I have problems when using the MVC in web programming, below is a class diagram that I made out of a sequence. Is it true that class `v_admin` does not have  attributes/operations?

If I am wrong, can you give advice on how to create a class from of a sequence diagram?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you need to provide something like a UML diagram, at least post images exported at a resolution as to make them readable.

Answer (score 0):

View certainly have variables relating to the display, or how else is the user going to do anything? Also having 2 "deleteUser" as an example doesn't seem right to me.

**MVC**

**M**odel: Is the core of the program, containing all the information needed to function, does not know about View or Control.

**V**iew: Contains display methods and a pointer to the model, so that it can access relevant information and display it to the user. (Think "Get".)

**C**ontroller: Contains a pointer to the model and view. Handles the user input and sends it to the model, usually it also uses API from view to update. Note that you could decouple the controller from the view by having the view observe data from the model to update the display. (Think "Set" and "update".)

Looking at your sequence diagram the above is not clear to me.

Here is an example I cooked up 
[image]

Comment: it is a from fill like to get username and password in view count to method or not?. Based on ur class mybe i need to add method updateView(). I actually now doing analysis and system design of its program have been made, so in the sequence method i matched form the program code. and in the code in clas view i didnt found method like updateView().

Comment: What do you mean by _having 2 "deleteUser" as an example_ ?

Comment: yah,.. em there two method is same name but different function. method deleteuser() in class admin is for set parameter table and data in method deleteUser(table,data) and refresh the web page after deleting file. deleteuser() in class m_admin is for delete file with his table and data as parameter in database.

Comment: @ArrofiRezaSatria I addressed the answerer. Anyhow, now I see you have two such methods and they are correct since they relate to different classes. Nothing wrong there. The controller delete forwards a delete to the model. You would not go from view directly to model.

Comment: Yeah maybe i should wrote it in diffrent name to differentiate between controller n model.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking: you can not construct a complete class from a sequence diagram. A SD represents only a part of the behavior of several classes which usually do not make use of all the operations. Only if you have some over-documented model (with respect to use of SDs) you may guess the operations of a class. But then again: not the  attributes.

However, what you can do is to make a good guess from a SD, if that's all you got. In this case you will start some kind of reengineering/refactoring.

Comment: Hmm,.. I saw my friend made a class diagram one by one from each SD and corrected by our lecture. and actuallay i know we should to gather all SD diagram to make complete class diagram. what do you think is better between that?

Comment: That's actually what I said: it's a reengineering process where you try to place the right jigsaw puzzle parts.